# When file contents change, send updated contents to user using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a node.js script to display the contents of a text file if the contents of the file changes.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

fs.watch("/Users/{username}/Desktop/data.txt",function(event,file) {

    fs.readFile('/Users/{username}/Desktop/data.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end(data);
        //^ this doesn't work, just returns a blank page

    });
});

}).listen(1337, '0.0.0.0');
```

Unfortunately, it only displays a blank page. What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: [meteor](http://meteor.com/) does this by default. You may want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");

function dataHandler(data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(data);
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

fs.watch("/Users/{username}/Desktop/data.txt",function(event,file) {

    fs.readFile('/Users/{username}/Desktop/data.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        dataHandler(data);

    });
});

}).listen(1337, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: No problem, glad I was of assistance.

Comment: @JackGreenhill would like to know what you did different, and how can `res` work(being out of scope)?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that whatever process changed the file did so by opening it in write mode and then rewriting it. When that happens you'll get the notification right after the other process has opened the file, at which point it will be empty because it hasn't been written to yet.

It's probably best to set a timeout that's triggered every time you get a change notification (i.e. each time you get notified while a timeout is pending, you clear the timeout and start a new one) and only read the file when the timeout completes.